# Как увеличивать значение style.left?

Tags: javascript

```
function right() {
   square.style.left += 50+'px';
}
```

Как устанавливать не фиксированное значение в style.left, а прибавлять\отнимать его ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Данное свойство является строкой, поэтому прежде чем увеличивать его, его надо перевести в число, например используя [функцию `parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

```
function right() {
   square.style.left = (parseInt(square.style.left,10)+50)+'px';
}
```

Пример:

```js
var square = document.getElementById('square');
square.onclick = function() {
  right()
}

function right() {
  square.style.left = (parseInt(square.style.left, 10) + 50) + 'px';
}
```

```css
#square {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lime;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="square" style="left:0"></div>
```

Стоит обратить внимание на то, что свойство `left` установлено в *inline* стилях, в противном случае оно будет равно пустой строке, и `parseInt(square.style.left, 10)` вернет *NaN*.

Другим вариантом, может быть использование [функции *getComputedStyle*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle), позволяющей получить текущее значение свойства, как значения по умолчанию, в случае, когда inline свойство пустое.

```js
var square = document.getElementById('square');
square.onclick = function() {
  right()
}

function right() {
  square.style.left = (parseInt(square.style.left || getComputedStyle(square)['left'], 10) + 50) + 'px';
}
```

```css
#square {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: lime;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="square" style="left:0"></div>
```

Comment: Должно бы заработать, но элемент `square` не сдвигается влево на 50px при вызове функции `right()`. Не могу понять, почему

Comment: @SergeyAlekseev, скорее всего потому, что у него стоит `position` не _absolute_, или _relative_, а еще возможно выбран какой-то другой `square`, либо вообще данная ссылка _null_ и в консоли пишется куча ошибок

Comment: Это предусмотрел - `position: absolute`
Вот полная картина:
`square.onclick = function() {right()}
function right() {
   square.style.left = (parseInt(square.style.left,10)+50)+'px';
}`

Comment: @SergeyAlekseev, где задается начальное положение этого элемента?

Comment: В html-документе этот элемент единственный в `body`.
`#square {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    cursor: pointer;
}`
Когда в функции `right()` было `square.style.left = 50+'px';`, то при клике на элемент он *один* раз всё же сдвигался вправо

Comment: @SergeyAlekseev `square.onclick = function() {this.style.left = (parseInt(this.style.left)+50)+'px'; }`

Comment: @Mihanik71, в данном случае без разницы, и использование _this_ скорее запутает, чем поможет

Comment: @SergeyAlekseev, обновил ответ

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо! 
Не могли бы Вы подсказать, как осуществить перемещение этого элемента по нажатию клавиш?
https://jsfiddle.net/9md3ynok/1/

Comment: @SergeyAlekseev, [вот тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597060/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-javascript) подсказывают, что стрелочки не всегда отлавливаются на keypress, и советуют использовать keydown. От себя добавлю, что это свойство - число, и лучше сравнивать его с числами, а не строками

Comment: @Grundy, Ваши замечания учел, но не работает:(
https://jsfiddle.net/9md3ynok/3/

Comment: @SergeyAlekseev, конечно не работает, потому что надо прочитать обновленный ответ, и посмотреть добавленные в него примеры.

Comment: @Grundy, обновил,
https://jsfiddle.net/9md3ynok/4/
Скажите, что не так?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43635/discussion-between-grundy-and-sergey-alekseev).